# How to manage List an Dict in Django views and Template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

When I iterate through a Query in Django my Dict only update the last item. Does anyone knows how to add all Query data on it.
It is wierd because if I create a list with the same Query it does get all data (as you can see just bellow vendor number 5 has two opening_hours ins List but not in Dict):

Query with a Dict:

```
dict_today_open_hour = {}
for t in v.today_opening_hours:      
dict_today_open_hour.update({t.vendor.id:{'today_from_hour': t.from_hour, 'today_to_hour': t.to_hour,}})
```

The Dict result is:

```
{1: {'today_from_hour': '07:00', 'today_to_hour': '20:00'}, 5: {'today_from_hour': '22:00', 'today_to_hour': '23:00'}}
```

Same Query with a List:

```
list_today_open_hour = []
for t in v.today_opening_hours:
list_today_open_hour.append({t.vendor.id:{'today_from_hour': t.from_hour, 'today_to_hour': t.to_hour,}})
```

List result:

```
[{1: {'today_from_hour': '07:00', 'today_to_hour': '20:00'}}, {5: {'today_from_hour': '09:00', 'today_to_hour': '19:00'}}, {5: {'today_from_hour': '22:00', 'today_to_hour': '23:00'}}]
```

As you can see in the List result I got all data from the Query but in the Dict result I only get the last item from vendor id number 5.

Does anyone knows if it is possible:
1-) Get all data in the Dict Query like the data i got from List? If so how to do it?
2-) Is it possible to user the Query List Result in template and filter it with the vendor id? Do something like this:

```
{% for l in list_today_open_hour %}
{% if l.0 == vendor.id %}
{{ l.1 }} - {{ l.2 }}
{% endif %}}
{% endfor %}}
```

I tryed to the above code to use the List from the Query result as it is complete but I could not get the vendor ID with "l.0" and I dont even know if it is possible.

If someone could help to explain those questions or give any directions on how to get it solved I will be very thankfull.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same key "5" in your key value pair in dictionary for 2 different items. i think that is why it replaces the "5" key item. because dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, they have unique keys for every item they have. but in a list it can have duplicate keys.

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. Is there a way to walk around this or a way to iterate the List in Django Template?

Comment: Try ```l['0']``` to get the key's value at ```l['0']```  or even try ```l[0]```.. another approach is ```l.get(0)```

Comment: It does not work. I think i must use something like zip. I wiil search more about Dict ant List. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to iterate through a List:

So if you have as my case a list like this:

```
[{'toh': {'vendor_id': 1, 'today_from_hour': '07:00', 'today_to_hour': '20:00'}}, {'toh': {'vendor_id': 5, 'today_from_hour': '16:00', 'today_to_hour': '19:00'}}, {'toh': {'vendor_id': 5, 'today_from_hour': '21:00', 'today_to_hour': '23:00'}}]
```

And you have to iterate through it to get each vendor id and show only that vendor's data you can do in views like this:

```
list_today_open_hour = []
for t in v.today_opening_hours:
list_today_open_hour.append({'toh':{'vendor_id': t.vendor.id,'today_from_hour': t.from_hour, 'today_to_hour': t.to_hour,}})

  for l in list_today_open_hour:
    print(l.get('toh'))
    d = (l.get('toh'))
    print(d['vendor_id'])
    vendor_id = (d['vendor_id'])
```

But if you do want to get that data in Django Template you should pass the List list_today_open_hours to Template and there you should use:

```
    {% for l in list_today_open_hour %}
    {{ l.toh.vendor_id }}
    {% if l.toh.vendor_id == vendor.id %}
    {{ l.toh.today_from_hour }} - {{ l.toh.today_to_hour }}
    {% else %}
```

That worked for me!!!

If anybody needs more explanetion fell free to ask me and it will be my pleasure to explain!

Thank you Muhammad you put me in the right way!

Comment: no problem at all, welcome :)